# In Haxe/Flambe, how do I go about rotating or scaling an Entity, so that its children are rotated at scaled proportionally

Tags: rotation, scale, haxe, flambe

I'm basically trying to emulate what you see in many other frameworks like Flash, XNA, etc. If I create a hierarchy of nested entities on stage, how do I rotate, scale, or translate a parent entity and have its children rotate, scale, and translate relative to the parent's origin point?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have this setup:

```
Entity (called enemy)  
> Sprite  
 -- Entity (called leg)  
  > ImageSprite  
 -- Entity (called arm)  
  > ImageSprite
 -- Entity
  > ImageSprite
```

If you want to rotate the enemy, you should do
enemy.get(Sprite).rotation._ = 35;
Then the whole character should rotate.

If you want to rotate a part of it, use
leg.get(Sprite).rotation.animateTo(35, 0.5, Ease.sineOut);

You can nest entities using addChild, and components (like Sprite) using add().
The displaylist is build using entities that contain Sprites, but not plain nested Sprites like Flash.

I suggest you could take a look at my Flambe guide, some basic concepts (that can be confusing at start) are explained in it
https://github.com/markknol/flambe-guide/wiki/

Have fun, please let know if you have questions.